# What are all the different species of intelligent beings that God has created?

Tags: angels, demons, 4-living-creatures

According to scripture, what intelligent life has God created in addition to humans, angels, and demons? One example I can think of are the 4 living creatures talked about in Revelation. Then there's Cherubim, Seraphim, etc... Is there anything else?

> **Revelation 4:6-8 ESV** And around the throne, on each side of the throne, are **four living creatures, full of eyes in front and behind**: the first living creature like a lion, the second living creature like an ox, the third living creature with the face of a man, and the fourth living creature like an eagle in flight. And the four living creatures, each of them with six wings, are full of eyes all around and within, and day and night they never cease to say, “Holy, holy, holy, is the Lord God Almighty, who was and is and is to come!”

I'd love an answer that contained the creature, where they're mentioned in scripture, and what we know about them or what they do. I'm fine with considering the prophetic visions of creatures because we don't know if those are to be taken literally or not.

---

Edit: I expanded the wording of the question just a little bit.

Comment: "Angel" is not an ontological category like "God," "human," or "cherubim"--it is a job title.

Comment: In including the prophetic visions means you want descriptions of the beasts in Daniel and Revelation too, right? I've never met anyone that thinks they are literally beasts or creatures of any kind.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a list question

Comment: @Bye Answers can be in a list format if that's what the answerer wants to do--at it's core it's a scriptural analysis question.

Comment: I think the question is plenty answerable. vtr.

Answer (score 5):

The Four Living Creatures in Revelation are also described in Ezekiel 10, when he has a vision of the Cherubim - which are either heavenly beings and/or angels depending on who you ask:

> And every one had four faces: **the first face was the face of a cherub, and the second face was the face of a man, and the third the face of a lion, and the fourth the face of an eagle.**

Also, to my understanding (at least in Revelation) these creatures are supposed to represent the Four Evangelists - Matthew, Mark, Luke, and John.

Depending on your denomination and what you do or do not consider scriptural, in *Mishneh Torah* or *Yad ha-Chazakh* we have the following:

**Chayot ha-Kodesh** - Ezekiel Chs 1-10 (creatures)
**Ophanim** - also in Ezekiel Chs 1-10 ("wheels")
**Erelim** - Isaiah 33:7
**Hashmallim** - Ezekiel 1:4
**Seraphim** - Isaiah 6
**Malakim** - regular angels/messengers; seen throughout
**Elohim** - "godly beings" (this is why the Lord is typically called Adonai Elohim)
**Bene Elohim** - the sons of God/godly beings
**Cherubim** - we see them throughout the Bible.
**Ishim** - manlike beings in Genesis 18:32 and Daniel 10:5
**Nephilim** - sons of the fallen angels (sometimes called "Watchers"). They were giants created after the angels exchanged in relations with human women.

*note I used Judaism as the reference for the names

Comment: Cool answer! Could you give a bit of detail to what the *Mishneh Torah* or *Yad ha-Chazakh* books are? Do a lot of people consider them inspired?

Comment: Some of these aren't necessarily specific creatures/species, right?

Comment: Rabbi Maimonides, one of the most influential Torah scholars to date to my knowledge, wrote it in the time between 1170 and 1180. If I remember correctly, it was written to clarify the Laws and how a Jewish person should approach their faith - laying down the stepping stones to "proper" Judaism. As you could imagine, old timey orthodox Jews were not very happy about it - but it was no less influential to their culture today,

Comment: @fredsbend in the beginning he asks "According to scripture, what intelligent life has God created that isn't a human, angel, or demon?" The Ophanim are wheels with eyes, while the Hashmallim are (at least as far as the "Hashmal" word is concerned) some form of energy, as it's word and translations mean "electricity." While not all are described as "angels", most are in a sense. The Chayot are the bearers of God's throne, for example, and don't have much more description.

Comment: Isn't there something like "the 24 Elders" too?

Comment: @fredsbend the 24 Elders are never specifically identified, but being that they are on thrones it's unlikely that they are angels or the like. Many consider them to be the Apostles and leaders of the original Twelve Tribes, while others consider them to be the physical embodiment of the Church since Christ speaks of the Church ruling with Him in Revelation 2:26-27, 5:10, 20:4; Matthew 19:28; Luke 22:30.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks for the info. Could you add a little snippet in the answer itself?

Comment: @Jesse. 'Old timey orthodox Jews'? Unless you are Jewish yourself or a comedian, slightly more polite language might be in order.

Comment: @LCIII a snippet? Pardon my confusion, I'm still a little new :) and gideonmarx the only person I can think of that could reasonably be offended by that wording is a Jew from that time. Judaism today is a far cry from medieval Judaism, and medieval Judaism was a far cry from NT-era Judaism. An example of this? Easy, they don't kill sinners like the Law tells them to (this isn't because its an old practice, its because the Sanhedrin don't sit in the court). My wording can't be edited, but if it offended you somehow, you have my sincerest apologies.